# Batty drain issue on CM10.2.1-yuga / Sony Xperia Z - NFC Service using over 50%

Tags: cyanogenmod, battery-life, nfc, services, sony-xperia-z

I've recently put CyanogenMod CM10.2.1-yuga on my Xperia Z and I've noticed the NFC server is using an insane amount of the battery.

[image: Screenshot of NFC Service battery usage]

Even after disabling the service in the App section, the service is still running and continues to drain battery:

[image: Screenshot of service disabled]

And the NFC section of my settings is greyed out

[image]

Any idea of what's going on or how to diagnose this further?

Comment: Try Calibrating your battery or try freezing nfc.apk and tag.apk. Did you post this in Cyanogenmod forum?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1.Try Calibrating your battery ( few says it is necessary to calibrate your phone after rom installation)

- Charge phone to 100%
- Boot in to recovery
- Wipe battery stats
- Reboot and drain the battery completely ( by playing or media or
  normal usage)
- After complete drain recharge the phone again to 100%

2.Try freezing or renaming or removing `nfc.apk and tag.apk` (Instead of removing the apk just try renaming them like `nfc.apk.bak`)